# Filter String by substring

Tags: typescript

I want to use `href` to open a mail-client via `mailto:`. I am using a class which contains pre- and surname of the person I want to mail.

`let mail: string ='mailto:' +person.getForeName() + '.' + person.getLastName() + '@example.de' ;`

The problem : the mail-adresses have no Umlauts and no titles, which the class contains.

I solved the problem with umlauts by using :

```
    mail = mail.replace('ü/g', 'ue');
    mail = mail.replace('ö/g', 'oe');
    mail = mail.replace('Ä/g', 'Ae');
    mail = mail.replace('Ü/g', 'Ue');
    mail = mail.replace('Ö/g', 'Öe');
```

but when I want to filter names like `Dr. Sample` it does not work.

So far I've tried to do it similar to my umlaut-approach:

```
mail = mail.replace('Dr\.', '');
```

but it does not replace the "Dr." substring.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works :

```js
mail = 'Dr. Sample'
console.log(mail.replace('Dr\.', ''))
```